# Laravel Elloquent, Sort relation to make it tree

Tags: laravel, relation, eloquent

i would like to generate Tree based on second layer of elloquent relation

I have 3 table that are :

> **User** (id, name)
>
> **Post** (id, parent_id, name)
>
> **Category** (user_id,post_id)

and i have sample table like:

**User**

> id  |  name
>
> 1   |  John Doe

**Post**

> id | parent_id | name
>
> 1  |  0             |   PostA
>
> 2  |  1             |   Post A.1
>
> 3  |  **4**             |   Post B.1
>
> 4  |  **0**             |   Post B

**Category**

> user_id    |  post_id
>
> 1 | 1
>
> 1 | 2
>
> 1 | 3
>
> 1 | 4

and my question is, how to sort the post from user to get tree?

```
@foreach($user->categories as $category)

  {{$category->post->name}}

@endfor
```

i would expect the result will be :

- PostA
- Post A.1
- **Post B (Not Post B.1)**
- **Post B.1**

Thank you, i really have no idea to solve this problem..

Comment: do you have any model implemented?

Comment: How do you get your query in your controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible smart solution (amongst any other, e.g. filtering from database) could be just sorting the `$user->categories` resulting collection.
Eloquent collections have a method for this:

`@foreach($user->categories->sortBy('name') as $category)`

Link to official docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sortby

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have named your pivot table unconventionally, but this code will help you.
First try to add children relationship  to your **post** model:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class,'parent_id','id');
}
```

This practical approach work for n number of categories with n number of children

First create a partial view `category.blade.php` file which recursively will call itself to load its children

```
<li>
   @if ($category->post->children()->count() > 0 )
       <ul>
           @foreach($category->post->->children as $category)

                   @include('category', $category) //the magic is in here

           @endforeach
       </ul>
   @endif
</li>
```

Then in the main view you add this code which loads all children recursively

```
<ul>
    @foreach ($user->categories as $category)

        @if($category->post->parent_id == 0 )

            @include('category', $category)

        @endif

    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: wow i think this might be the solution.. thanks a lot, it save me!